# SQL Server Auto-Increment Next INSERT Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, null, auto-increment

I have a good background in MySQL, but I am new to the ins and outs of SQL Server. I'll ask my question by setting up and solving the exact same issue in MySQL:

---

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stuff` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Insert a value into the table:

```
INSERT INTO `example` (
  `id`, `stuff`
) VALUES (
  NULL, 'Hello World'
) ;
```

By executing the query above, the `id` column will automatically receive the next available integer for use as a primary key, no work involved on my part.

However, trying the same idea when inserting a row into an SQL Server table of type `int` gives me this error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'database.user.example'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (severity 16) ...
```

What can be used in an SQL Server `INSERT` query that will automatically increment the primary key like MySQL does with a `NULL` value?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set the column to be an IDENTITY column in the column definition?

```
CREATE TABLE example (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), Stuff VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO example (Stuff) VALUES ('Hello World!')
```

Comment: Ahh... no I omitted that. MySQL syntax handles that bit differently. That's good to know about that! Is there a way that I can `ALTER` the table to slip this value in, or does the table have to be dropped?

Comment: Never mind... I can just create a new column and drop the old one. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

That's an identity column you need.  and @Mark Byers was correct.  Just omit the column

Comment: Oops I didn't notice that he hadn't declared it as IDENTITY. I thought the OP had already figured that part out!